# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not dict python error

Tags: python, integer

So im trying to get this code to work and im quite new at coding with python, im using pysimplegui too and im getting this error 'TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not dict'

with this code

```
    name_arr = [];

    with open('team.json') as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)

    for i in data['team']:
        name_arr.append(i['Team Name'])

    #Sort names alphabetically
    name_arr = sorted(name_arr)

    event_arr = ['Basketball','100m','Climbing']
        
    layout = [[sg.Button('Main menu')],
              [sg.Text('Record result for:'),sg.Combo(name_arr)],
              [sg.Text('Event:'),sg.Combo(event_arr)],
              [sg.Text('Finishing position:'),sg.Combo(list(range(1,21)))],
              [sg.Button('Save result')]]

    window = sg.Window('My Tournament Program - record result',layout,size=(700, 600))

    while True:#Keep the window open until button pressed
        event, values = window.Read()
        if event is None or event == "Done":
            break
        if event == "Main menu":
            print('Loading main menu window...')
            window.Close()
            self.main_menu()
            break
        if event == "Save result":
            print('Saving result... add more code below')
            #Open competitors file
            with open('team.json') as json_file:
               data = json.load(json_file)

            for i in data['team']:
               #Find the selected competitor by their name
               if i['Team Name'] == values[0]:
                   #name found in file
                   #Update to include their result
                   #Score is 21 minus finishing position e.g. 20 pts for 1st
                   data['team'][i]['Score'] = 20 - values[2]

            #Save data competitors file
            try:
                with open('team.json', 'w') as f:
                    json.dump(data, f)
                    print("Score saved succesfully.")

            except IOError as e:
                    print("I/O error({0}): {1}").format(e.errno, e.strerror)
                    print("Error saving team")
    window.Close()
```

can anyone help me figure it out, im guessing its something to do with this line

data['team'][i]['Score'] = 20 - values[2]

but not sure..

Answer (score 1):

In this `for` loop:

```
            for i in data['team']:
               #Find the selected competitor by their name
               if i['Team Name'] == values[0]:
                   #name found in file
                   #Update to include their result
                   #Score is 21 minus finishing position e.g. 20 pts for 1st
                   data['team'][i]['Score'] = 20 - values[2]
```

`i` is an actual *item* in `data['team']` (that is, it's a `dict` in a `list` of `dict`s), not the *index* of one of those items (which would be an `int`).

Since `i` is the dict you want to modify, you should be able to just change the offending line to:

```
                   i['Score'] = 20 - values[2]
```

Unrelated, I'd suggest changing this line:

```
event, values = window.Read()
```

to something like:

```
event, (team_name, _, finishing_pos) = window.Read()
```

so that you don't have to remember the individual indices of `values`:

```
            for i in data['team']:
               #Find the selected competitor by their name
               if i['Team Name'] == team_name:
                   #name found in file
                   #Update to include their result
                   #Score is 21 minus finishing position e.g. 20 pts for 1st
                   i['Score'] = 20 - finishing_pos
```

Comment: Thanks, took me ages to try figure it out haha

Comment: `event, values = window.Read()` cannot be replaced by something like `event, (team_name, _, finishing_pos) = window.Read()`. Basically, `values` will be a dictionary or `None`.

Comment: It gives you a dictionary with int keys rather than a list or tuple?  How perverse.  (I'm not at all familiar with `pysimplegui`, heh.)